# javax.imagio.IIOException when trying to load image file from runnable jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ioexception

I am building a helper tool, which will add some text to an image. The image is located in the same directory as the .jar file. I just want to copy the file into the jar's directory and double click the jar file, and it should process the image.

When I run the code in eclipse, everything works fine. (Image is in the root folder of the project here)

But when I export it to a jar(image file in same directory), I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
```

at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
  at main.main(main.java:21)

This is how the code starts:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(new File("./bgimage.jpg"));
    int fontSize=120;
```

(line 19 , 20 and 21)

I tried every possible variation of the file name and searched for hours for the problem. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Hope this [link](https://www.dyclassroom.com/image-processing-project/how-to-read-and-write-image-file-in-java)  helps

Comment: The error even occurs, when I use an absolute File Path like "D\\folder\\image.png" as mentioned, it always works in eclipse, but in the .jar file it doesn't

Comment: can you post exact line number  from the error message where you getting the error and code ? Here in above comment colon is missing in the path "D:\\folder\\image.png"

Comment: Is the image **within** the jar file? If so, don't use File but rather resources.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try to explain it more properly. The image file is NOT within the jar file. It is supposed to be like next to the jar File in the same folder in Windows Explorer.

Comment: @Karthik - it was just an example. The posted code is lines 19, 20 and 21 of my code and that is were the exception is thrown...

Comment: I NEED to be able to change the image file after creation of the source file, that's why I don't want it to be within the jar file...

Comment: Check whether other Java library packages can see the file.  For instance: `System.out.println(Files.exists(Paths.get("./bgimage.jpg")));`

Answer (score 1):

Try to find out what your working dir is and print the absolute path of the file:

```
System.out.println("Working dir: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));

File file = new File("./bgimage.jpg");
System.out.println("File: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
```